# Error Undeclared identifier in Pine Script

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, pine-script-v4

I'm trying to write a code that buys if the 20 day moving average is above the 50 day moving average and the 20 hour moving average crosses above the 50 hour moving average. Close the trade when the 20 hour moving average cross under the 50 hour moving average
I wrote this code and it is giving me an error Undeclared identifier 'slowHA'. I did declare slowHA. so what is wrong with this code?

```
//@version=4
strategy("MA Crossover")

// Define the daily moving averages
fastDA = sma(close, 20)
slowDA = sma(close, 50)

// Define the hourly moving averages
fastHA := sma(close, 20, "hour")
slowHA := sma(close, 50, "hour")

// Buy when fast DA is above slow DA and fast HA crosses above slow HA
longCondition = fastDA > slowDA and crossover(fastHA, slowHA)
if (longCondition)
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long)

// Sell when slow DA is below fast DA and slow HA crosses below fast HA
shortCondition = crossunder(fastHA, slowHA)
if (shortCondition)
    strategy.close("Long")

// Plot the moving averages
plot(fastDA, color = color.red, linewidth = 2, title = "Fast DA")
plot(slowDA, color = color.blue, linewidth = 2, title = "Slow DA")
plot(fastHA, color = color.orange, linewidth = 1, title = "Fast HA", style = plot.style_line)
plot(slowHA, color = color.green, linewidth = 1, title = "Slow HA", style = plot.style_line)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error comes from :

```
fastHA := sma(close, 20, "hour")
```

Then it creates a lot of other error.
Correct line one by one from this one, your errors will disappears.

Also, please use the version 5 of Pinescript as the V4 is outdated.

Answer (score 0):

*fastHA* and *slowHA* are [mutable variables](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/language/Expressions_declarations_and_statements.html#variable-assignment), and must be previously assigned

```
fastHA = 0.0
slowHA = 0.0
```